# PostgreSQL to list out a query and then the last line include a sum

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a query that displays a count of the orders by users name and then i want to display the total for all users on the last line as so:

i have a table `orders` that includes
`username | order# | amount | etc`

I would like to display the result like this:

`batman   | 65
 superman | 25
 robin    | 40
     Sum:  130`

Is this possible using one query?
Currently i am using two separate queries:

`select username, count(*) as "Number of Orders"
 from orders
 group by username;`

AND

`select count(*) as "Number of Orders"
 from orders;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grouping sets`:

```
select username, count(*) as "Number of Orders"
from orders
group by grouping sets ((username), ());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION ALL`

```
select username, count(*) as "Number of Orders"
from orders
group by username

UNION ALL

select NULL, count(*)
from orders;
```